# Как в nuxt подключить модули vuex к конкретной странице?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, frontend, vuex, nuxt.js

В nuxt есть папка store, куда можно добавлять файлы с модулями vuex, далее эти модули будут автоматически добавлены на все страницы в vuex stor.

**А как сделать так, что бы в nuxt модули vuex добавлялись только на определённые страницы?**

*Просто у меня есть несколько очень больших и сложных vuex модулей со специфичным stor и мутациями, которые нужны только на определённых страницах и не нужны везде, и не хочется сильно увеличивать ими размеры бандла на всех страницах...*

Comment: ` <script src="https://unpkg.com/vuex@3.0.1/dist/vuex.js"></script>`

Answer (score 0):

Модуль создаётся не на странице, а в отдельном файле и подключается к другому модулю (в нашем случае к рутовому), после чего становится частью глобального стора. В компонентах же вы только обращаетесь к модулям  и не можете управлять их доступностью, они могут существовать или не существовать. Если же вам нужна мутация, скажем, в компоненте 1, то вы получаете ее (например через `mapMutations`) внутри компонента 1 и она будет доступна только в нем.

P.S. - Да, вы можете регистрировать модуль в компоненте, но тогда мы будем говорить уже не об описанной вами проблеме, а о том, что мы будем регистрировать модуль при использовании компонента и удалять его при уничтожении. То есть поведение будет идентично тому, что я описал выше с разницей в том когда модуль будет появляться в сторе и когда исчезать, но пока он будет в сторе - он будет доступен везде. Действительно ли вам это нужно?

Answer (score -1):

`https://unpkg.com/vuex@3.0.1/dist/vuex.js` - подключите файл к старанице
https://vuex.vuejs.org/ru/installation.html

Comment: Так в nuxt уже есть vuex, и папка store для модулей vuex, и сам vuex нужен на всех страницах, но некоторые модули vuex, нужны не на всех страницах сайта, а только на определённых, и я не совсем понимаю как это сделать в архитектуре nuxt т.к. сейчас все модули из папки store подключаются на все страницы в папке page т.е. на все страницы сайте.

Comment: Т.е. у меня есть страница с оформлением заказа, есть модуль vuex там есть свой формат данных, с кучей мутаций и экшенов, и в результате модуль достаточно тяжёлый и я не хочу что бы он был на всех страницах сайта т.к. он там не нужен, он нужен только на странице оформления заказа, а nuxt автоматом вставляет его на все страницы в vuex

Comment: тогда, наверное, вопрос следует задавать иначе: "Как отключить Vuex на конкретной странице?"

Comment: Нет. Сам vuex нужен на всех страницах и некоторые его модули нужны везде. Но часть модулей нужна только на определённых страницах. Я думал в сторону метода registerModule из vuex, но потом подумал, по может в nuxt, уже есть что нибудь для этого, что бы оно не выбивалось из общей системы, но похоже, что нету.

Comment: ,на всякий случай, уточню, что под модулями, я имею ввиду - https://vuex.vuejs.org/ru/guide/modules.html